# How to get the name of user that belongs to foreign key using Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I want to get the name of User where belongs the foreign key using Laravel Eloquent.

I have posts Model:

```
Class Posts Extends Eloquent{
protected $table = 'posts';
protected $fillable = array('title, image, text, user_id');
public $timestamps = false;

}
```

and 
User Model:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

I want to send to controller the value of user name, title, text, image to view.

```
public function index(){
    // get all the bears
        $posts = Posts::all();
      return View::make('welcome', compact('posts'));
  }
```

Comment: You need to set up the [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: @aynber i would love some example for this, because the docs of laravel is ambigous

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the one to many relationship between the models as,

```
class Posts extends Model
{
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
    // Whatever your code in Post model
}


class User extends Model
{
    public function posts(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }
    // Whatever your code in User model
}
```

as explained in the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many). Now you can get the name of the user that the post is belonged to each post.

Define the route as
Route::get('/all-posts','PostController@getAllPosts')->name('get_all_posts');

Write the controller class to get the posts

```
class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function getAllPosts() {  
         $posts = Posts::all();
    
         foreach ($posts as $post){
    
            $username = $post->user->name;
            //do something with $username
    
        }
        return view('all_posts')->with('detailed_posts');
        //here the $detailed_posts can be defined in the 'do something' above
    }
}
```

Here at do something  you can create a new array of username and pass it to the view,

or

set the PostController as,

```
class PostController extends Controller
    {
        public function getAllPosts() {  
           return view(all_posts);
    }
}
```

and then set the all_posts.blade.php to directly access the username in the view using blade syntax as follow ,

```
<html>
    <div>
        <h1>All Posts</h1> 
        @foreach (App\Post::all() as $post)
            <span> Title : {{ $post->title}}</span>
            <span> Username: {{$post->user->name}}</span>
            .......
        @endforeach
    </div>
</html>
```

Comment: routers are being used, but haven't shown in the code here. With routers only you get into controller methods

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'work.users' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `users` where `users`.`id` is null limit 1)

Comment: Have you done the migrations? Did you create a user table in the database?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153176/discussion-between-nodejscodrd-and-achala-dissanayake).

Answer (score 1):

To set up the relationship for the Users -> Posts, then you can use `hasMany`

```
public function posts(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}
```

This will look for any `user_id` on the posts table. If it's named differently, then you can pass it in as the second parameter.

```
public function posts(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post', name_of_column_in_post_table, name_of_column_in_user_table);
}
```

In the posts table, you want either `hasOne` or `belongsTo`. Both work the same way:

```
public function users() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', name_of_column_in_user_table, name_of_column_in_post_table);
}
```

You can then get the user information by doing `$post->user->name`

Comment: This code is implemented in the Model of User?? or the controller?? @aynber please clarify.

Comment: The `posts` function goes in the `User` model, and the `user` function goes in the `Posts` model.

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'work.users' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `users` where `users`.`id` is null limit 1)

Comment: Then your User model needs some tweaking. What *is* the name of your users table?

Comment: i have the name as user in the table

Comment: Eloquent expects the table name to be the plural of the class name. If the table name is just `user`, then you need to add `protected $table = 'user';` to your User class.

Answer (score 1):

In the Model Class add the Relation like

```
Class Posts Extends Eloquent{
  protected $table = 'posts';
  protected $fillable = array('title, image, text, user_id');
  public $timestamps = false;
  public function user()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id);
  }
}
```

Now in the controller or view in every instance of Post you can use:
By Example

```
$post->user
```

Read the documentation about many to one relationship and even eager loading.

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'work.users' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `users` where `users`.`id` is null limit 1)